# Why is reading from file function crashing?

Tags: c, file, fgets, strcpy

Trying to read multiple line from file to store them in a structure made up of the string elements, however when I run the program it simply crashes and I haven't the faintest idea why.

function in question:

```
Hashtbl* loadfromfile(Hashtbl* hashtbl, char *path){
    int i = 0;
    char line[100];
    char* string[40];

    FILE *f = fopen(path, "r");

    if(f == NULL){
        printf("FILE NO FOUND!");
    }else{
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)!=NULL){
           strcpy(string[i],line);
           i++;
       }
       fclose(f);
       for(i = 0; i<(SIZE*2); i++){
            strcpy(hashtbl[i].subscript, string[i]);
            i++;
       }

       for(i = 1; i<(SIZE*2); i++){
           strcpy(hashtbl[i].value, string[i]);
           i++;
       }

       return hashtbl;
       }
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "hashtable.h"

int main() {

    Hashtbl* numbers;
    numbers = init_hashtbl(); //init_hashtable initialises numbers
    loadfromfile(numbers, "test.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%s1", numbers[i].subscript);
        printf("%s2\n", numbers[i].value);
    }
}
```

Hashtable structure:

```
typedef struct Hashtbls{
    char *subscript;
    char *value;
} Hashtbl;
```

init_hasthable function:

```
   Hashtbl* init_hashtbl(){
       Hashtbl* hashtbl;
       hashtbl = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(Hashtbl));
       for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++){
           hashtbl[i].subscript = "ZERO";
           hashtbl[i].value = "ZERO";
       }
       return hashtbl;
   }
```

Comment: `if(f == NULL){
            printf("FILE NO FOUND!");
        }` - Why carry on? You should stop processing at this point

Comment: `strcpy(string[i],line);` - You have not allocated space for this

Comment: Show us `init_hashtbl`, `Hashtbls.subscript` and `Hashtbls.value` might not be initialized. Also `char* string[40];` is not initialized, so `strcpy(string[i],line);` is trying to write through a pointer pointing to nowhere.

Comment: `while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)!=NULL){` -> Should be be checking that i is under 40?

Comment: If you want to be a developer you're going to have to learn to debug your code. Get thee to a debugger - GO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few problems here:

```
if(f == NULL){
    printf("FILE NO FOUND!");
}
```

If the file cannot be opened, then you cannot continue. Also the message might
be printed way later, use `printf("FILE NOT FOUND!\n");` instead.

```
char* string[40];
...
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), f)!=NULL){
    strcpy(string[i],line);
    i++;
}
```

`string` is an array of uninitialized pointers, you cannot write anything
there. You should do

```
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, f))
{
    string[i] = malloc(strlen(line) + 1);
    if(string[i] == NULL)
    {
        // error handling is needed
    }
    strcpy(string[i], line);
    i++;
    if(i == sizeof string / sizeof *string)
        break;
}

// or if your system has strdup

while(fgets(line, sizeof line, f))
{
    string[i] = strdup(line);
    if(string[i] == NULL)
    {
        // error handling is needed
    }
    i++;
    if(i == sizeof string / sizeof *string)
        break;
}
```

Also you are not checking whether you read more than 40 lines. I did that with
the the last `if`. `sizeof array / sizeof *array` returns the number of
elements that an array can hold. Note that this only works for arrays, not
pointers, since in general `sizeof array != sizeof pointer`. Also don't forget
to free the allocated memory afterwards.

```
strcpy(hashtbl[i].subscript, string[i]);
...
strcpy(hashtbl[i].value, string[i]);
```

Are the `subscript` and `value` parameters here initialized in some way? Check
your `init_hashtbl()`.

---

**EDIT**

Now that you posted `init_hashtbl`:

```
for(i = 0; i<(SIZE*2); i++){
    strcpy(hashtbl[i].subscript, string[i]);
    i++;
}
```

You are initializing `subscript` and `value` with string literals, they
are pointing to read-only memory location, `strcpy` is going to fail. You have
to either allocate memory with `malloc` or change your structure with arrays.

**Option 1**

Keep the structure, change `init_hashtbl`

```
Hashtbl* init_hashtbl(){
   Hashtbl* hashtbl;
   hashtbl = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(Hashtbl));
   for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++){
       hashtbl[i].subscript = malloc(SOME_MAXIMAL_LENGTH + 1);
       strcpy(hashtbl[i].subscript, "ZERO");

       hashtbl[i].value = malloc(SOME_MAXIMAL_LENGTH + 1);
       strcpy(hashtbl[i].value, "ZERO");
   }
   return hashtbl;
}
```

You should always check the return value of `malloc`/`calloc`. Also the
problem here is that if you want to copy a string that is longer than
`SOME_MAXIMAL_LENGTH`, you are going to have a buffer overflow. So you should
use realloc in the reading routine:

```
for(i = 0; i<(SIZE*2); i++){
    char *tmp = realloc(hashtbl[i].subscript, strlen(string[i]) + 1);
    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        // error handling
    }

    hashtbl[i].subscript = tmp;
    strcpy(hashtbl[i].subscript, string[i]);
    i++;
}
```

If you don't want to deal with `realloc` here, you have to make sure, that no
`string[i]` is longer than `SOME_MAXIMAL_LENGTH`.

**Option 2**

Change you structure and init:

```
typedef struct Hashtbls{
    char subscript[SOME_MAXIMAL_LENGTH];
    char value[SOME_MAXIMAL_LENGTH];
} Hashtbl;


Hashtbl* init_hashtbl(){
   Hashtbl* hashtbl;
   hashtbl = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(Hashtbl));
   for(int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++){
       strcpy(hashtbl[i].subscript, "ZERO");
       strcpy(hashtbl[i].value, "ZERO");
   }
   return hashtbl;
}
```

Then in `loadfromfile` you don't have to deal with the `realloc` as shown
above, you can keep your code. However, you have to check that no `string[i]`
is longer than `SOME_MAXIMAL_LENGTH - 1`, otherwise buffer overflow.

One last thing, `fgets` reads a whole line, assuming that the length of the
line is lesser than `sizeof line`, the newline character will be added to the
line. You most likely don't want to have that. One way of getting rid of the
newline is:

```
fgets(line, sizeof line, f);
int len = strlen(line);
if(line[len - 1] == '\n')
    line[len - 1] = 0;
```

Comment: Very good effort and very good catch to explain trimming the trailing `'\n'` from `line`.

Comment: And error messages should be printed on `stderr`, not `stdout`.  That's what it is for.

Comment: worked like a charm thanks, and thanks especially for taking the time to explain everything so thoroughly